# Separate the ignore-time-filter checkbox from the top post

Tags: bug, flags, user-interface, moderator-tools

In the "flags" view of the Moderator Tools dashboard, there's a horizontal line between each listed flagged item and the next. But [the "ignore time filter" checkbox](/q/292878) appears atop the first-listed item, below the top line. This is confusing: that's where I'd expect UI relevant to only the top item. Several times, I've clicked that checkbox's label instead of the top post's title. Can you please put a line beneath the checkbox instead of (or in addition to) above it?

Comment: [bug] or [feature-request]? Seems like the latter to me.

Comment: @Mithrandir, it's an [improvement-request], ideally, but that's not an option. I called it a [bug] because the current UI causes problems; if it were causing no problems but I had an idea for making it even better I'd call it a [feature-request].